# Unable to get the HTML Table and colors to show correctly

Tags: html, css, magento

http://www.acuity-sports.com/baseball-softball/batting-cages/custom-netting/1-8-mm-barrier-net.html

Not sure why the tables and background colors are not showing up in the description field.

Comment: go to http://www.acuity-sports.com/skin/frontend/default/sm_sport/css/addons.css Line no 5 and remove border: 0 none; and     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; from here

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your http://www.acuity-sports.com/skin/frontend/default/sm_sport/css/addons.css **CSS** file, you have this code:

```
body, 
html, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend, button,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: transparent;
}
```

the property `background: transparent;` is causing your problem so remove it ..

or add the background color to your cells using **CSS** not **HTML**, so instead of:

```
<td bgcolor="#FF0000" style="text-align: center;">
    <strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; CN250 &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong>
</td>
```

Use this:

```
<td style="text-align: center; background: #FF0000;">
    <strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; CN250 &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong>
</td>
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

It's the background:transparent in your css file addons.css, line 14.

You can delete it or if you can't specify the background of the cell in css, not in HTML.